# How to pass a form input value to jQuery countdown function

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am a novice at this so any help with examples would be greatly appreciated.

I'm trying build a web page that allows users to upload images and set a countdown clock to when their post expires, withing a 28 day period.

Having problem trying to pass date value from the form input to the timeText element in the jquery function.

I've searched the web for answers in the past 48hrs and I'd have to tell ya, I am now total confused.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery("#DIV_TO_PLACE_COUNTDOWN").jCountdown({
      timeText:'2013/12/21 21:30:00',
      timeZone:8,
      onFinish:function(){
          alert("finish");
      }
  });

});
</script>

<form name="form1" action="" method="post">Enter Type: yyyy/mm/dd hr:mn:sc<BR>
<input type="text" name="timeText" id="timeText" value=""><P>
<input type="submit" name="submit" Value="Click" onClick="timeText(this.form)">
</form>
```

Comment: Pass the value of the form field to a function that starts the ginger. Use a reasonable id for where the timer will be displayed. Maybe take a step back and do something easier first to learn.

Comment: Do you want to change the text of #timeText? If yes, you can use jQuery .text() (http://api.jquery.com/text/)

Comment: Timer, not ginger. Auto-correcting phone.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't check it but should work:

```
$("#timeText").change(function() {
    $("#DIV_TO_PLACE_COUNTDOWN").jCountdown({
        timeText:$("#DIV_TO_PLACE_COUNTDOWN").value(),
        timeZone:8,
        onFinish:function(){
            alert("finish");
        }
    });
});
```

Maybe you will need to replace `$("#DIV_TO_PLACE_COUNTDOWN").value()` with `$("#DIV_TO_PLACE_COUNTDOWN").text()`